# How to calculate multiple row means grouped by column suffix in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing wide data and a simplified example would look something like this:

```r
#Generate random sample data:
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:10,
                 "A_0m" = runif(10, 50, 100), 
                 "B_0m" = runif(10, 30, 100), 
                 "A_1m" = runif(10, 50, 70), 
                 "B_1m" = runif(10, 5, 50)) %>% round(1)
```

Now I would like to calculate the row means from variable `A_0m` + `B_0m` and `A_1m` + `B_1m` respectively and adding the results as a new variable to the data frame. My actual dataset has many more variables.

My desired result would look something like this:

```r
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(
          row_mean_1 = mean(c(A_0m,B_0m)),
          row_mean_2 = mean(c(A_1m,B_1m)))

# A tibble: 10 × 6
# Rowwise: 
    A_0m  B_0m  A_1m  B_1m row_mean_1 row_mean_2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1    88    61    63    49       74.5       56  
 2    85    46    60     9       65.5       34.5
 3    71    60    68    29       65.5       48.5
 4    70    83    51    42       76.5       46.5
 5    80    80    53    17       80         35  
 6    55    35    69    38       45         53.5
 7    78    56    62    10       67         36  
 8    85    53    59    28       69         43.5
 9    59    94    68    36       76.5       52  
10    90    38    63    22       64         42.5
```

But this solution is not viable, as my real data has many more variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With larger datasets, `rowwise()` can be prohibitively slow. You may want to pivot to long format, group by the integer index, and then compute group means. This will work for any number of column groupings, so long as they follow the same naming convention.

```
library(tidyverse)

row_means <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID) |> 
  group_by(ID, name_ix =str_extract(name, '\\d')) |> 
  summarise(row_mean = mean(value)) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, 
              names_from = name_ix,
              values_from = row_mean,
              names_prefix = "row_mean_")
row_means
      ID row_mean_0 row_mean_1
   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1       80.7       58.0
 2     2       75.6       54.8
 3     3       73.9       49.4
 4     4       82.2       55.4
 5     5       67.1       34.6
 6     6       72.6       45.4
 7     7       61.8       50  
 8     8       63.8       38.3
 9     9       65.3       37.6
10    10       84.8       34.2
```

Now it is fast to join the output to the original `df`:

```
df |> left_join(row_means, by = "ID")

   ID A_0m B_0m A_1m B_1m row_mean_0 row_mean_1
1   1 64.4 97.0 67.8 48.3      80.70      58.05
2   2 89.4 61.7 63.9 45.6      75.55      54.75
3   3 70.4 77.4 62.8 36.1      73.90      49.45
4   4 94.2 70.1 69.9 40.8      82.15      55.35
5   5 97.0 37.2 63.1  6.1      67.10      34.60
6   6 52.3 93.0 64.2 26.5      72.65      45.35
7   7 76.4 47.2 60.9 39.1      61.80      50.00
8   8 94.6 32.9 61.9 14.7      63.75      38.30
9   9 77.6 53.0 55.8 19.3      65.30      37.55
10 10 72.8 96.8 52.9 15.4      84.80      34.15
```

Comment: Thank you very much @andrew_reece. Worked very well and I find it comprehensible.

Comment: You're welcome!  If this solution answered your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark next to this answer.  That will signal to others that this question has been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential approach:

```r
#Generate random sample data:
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:10,
                 "A_0m" = runif(10, 50, 100), 
                 "B_0m" = runif(10, 30, 100), 
                 "A_1m" = runif(10, 50, 70), 
                 "B_1m" = runif(10, 5, 50)) %>% round(1)

df %>%
  mutate((across(starts_with("A"), .names = "row_mean_{col}") + 
            across(starts_with("B"))) / 2) %>%
  rename_with(~gsub("A_|m$", "", .x), starts_with("row_mean_"))
#>    ID A_0m B_0m A_1m B_1m row_mean_0 row_mean_1
#> 1   1 64.4 97.0 67.8 48.3      80.70      58.05
#> 2   2 89.4 61.7 63.9 45.6      75.55      54.75
#> 3   3 70.4 77.4 62.8 36.1      73.90      49.45
#> 4   4 94.2 70.1 69.9 40.8      82.15      55.35
#> 5   5 97.0 37.2 63.1  6.1      67.10      34.60
#> 6   6 52.3 93.0 64.2 26.5      72.65      45.35
#> 7   7 76.4 47.2 60.9 39.1      61.80      50.00
#> 8   8 94.6 32.9 61.9 14.7      63.75      38.30
#> 9   9 77.6 53.0 55.8 19.3      65.30      37.55
#> 10 10 72.8 96.8 52.9 15.4      84.80      34.15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is `dplyover::across2()`. This will be an overkill for two column pairs, but if you have many column pairs this approach has its benefits.

Disclaimer: The {dplyover} package is not on CRAN, it is not very performant when working with grouped or rowwise data and I'm the maintainer.

Below we iterate over column pairs that start with `A_` and `B_`. We can use an anonymous function to get the mean of both columns. The `.names` argument allows to create flexible names on the fly, below `"row_names_"` followed by the common suffix `{suf}`. Since this includes `m` at the end, we can further use `.names_fn` to apply a function to finalize the names. Here we just delete the trailing `m`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(across2(starts_with("A_"),
                 starts_with("B_"),
                 \(x, y) mean(c(x, y), na.rm = TRUE),
                 .names = "row_mean_{suf}",
                 .names_fn = \(nm) gsub("m$", "", nm)
                 )
         )

#> # A tibble: 10 × 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       ID  A_0m  B_0m  A_1m  B_1m row_mean_0 row_mean_1
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1  64.4  97    67.8  48.3       80.7       58.0
#>  2     2  89.4  61.7  63.9  45.6       75.6       54.8
#>  3     3  70.4  77.4  62.8  36.1       73.9       49.4
#>  4     4  94.2  70.1  69.9  40.8       82.2       55.4
#>  5     5  97    37.2  63.1   6.1       67.1       34.6
#>  6     6  52.3  93    64.2  26.5       72.6       45.4
#>  7     7  76.4  47.2  60.9  39.1       61.8       50  
#>  8     8  94.6  32.9  61.9  14.7       63.8       38.3
#>  9     9  77.6  53    55.8  19.3       65.3       37.6
#> 10    10  72.8  96.8  52.9  15.4       84.8       34.2
```

Data from OP:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:10,
                 "A_0m" = runif(10, 50, 100), 
                 "B_0m" = runif(10, 30, 100), 
                 "A_1m" = runif(10, 50, 70), 
                 "B_1m" = runif(10, 5, 50)) %>% round(1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `c_across`

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(row_mean_1 = mean(c_across(ends_with("_0m"))),
         row_mean_2 = mean(c_across(ends_with("_1m"))))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       ID  A_0m  B_0m  A_1m  B_1m row_mean_1 row_mean_2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1  64.4  97    67.8  48.3       80.7       58.0
#>  2     2  89.4  61.7  63.9  45.6       75.6       54.8
#>  3     3  70.4  77.4  62.8  36.1       73.9       49.4
#>  4     4  94.2  70.1  69.9  40.8       82.2       55.4
#>  5     5  97    37.2  63.1   6.1       67.1       34.6
#>  6     6  52.3  93    64.2  26.5       72.6       45.4
#>  7     7  76.4  47.2  60.9  39.1       61.8       50  
#>  8     8  94.6  32.9  61.9  14.7       63.8       38.3
#>  9     9  77.6  53    55.8  19.3       65.3       37.6
#> 10    10  72.8  96.8  52.9  15.4       84.8       34.2
```

and a little more convoluted if you want to automate every group:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(ends_with("m")) |>
  mutate(grp = sub(".*_(\\d)m$", "\\1", name))|>
  mutate(row_mean = mean(value), 
         .by = c(ID, grp)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, names_prefix = "row_mean", values_from = row_mean) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)|>
  reframe(across(everything(), \(x) x[!is.na(x)]), .by = ID)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#>       ID row_mean0 row_mean1  A_0m  B_0m  A_1m  B_1m
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1      80.7      58.0  64.4  97    67.8  48.3
#>  2     2      75.6      54.8  89.4  61.7  63.9  45.6
#>  3     3      73.9      49.4  70.4  77.4  62.8  36.1
#>  4     4      82.2      55.4  94.2  70.1  69.9  40.8
#>  5     5      67.1      34.6  97    37.2  63.1   6.1
#>  6     6      72.6      45.4  52.3  93    64.2  26.5
#>  7     7      61.8      50    76.4  47.2  60.9  39.1
#>  8     8      63.8      38.3  94.6  32.9  61.9  14.7
#>  9     9      65.3      37.6  77.6  53    55.8  19.3
#> 10    10      84.8      34.2  72.8  96.8  52.9  15.4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split the data.frame into several different dataframes based on the numeric index from "A_0m" (0) , "B_1m" (1)....
And then do the mutate operation in a loop, and finally bind the data.frames back together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
    select(-1) |> 
    {\(x)split.default(x, parse_number(names(x)))}() |> 
    imap(\(x,y) mutate(x, "{y}_mean" := rowMeans(x))) |> 
    list_cbind() |> 
    bind_cols(index = df[[1]]) |> 
    unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 10 × 7
    A_0m  B_0m `0_mean`  A_1m  B_1m `1_mean` index
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1  64.4  97       80.7  67.8  48.3     58.0     1
 2  89.4  61.7     75.6  63.9  45.6     54.8     2
 3  70.4  77.4     73.9  62.8  36.1     49.4     3
 4  94.2  70.1     82.2  69.9  40.8     55.4     4
 5  97    37.2     67.1  63.1   6.1     34.6     5
 6  52.3  93       72.6  64.2  26.5     45.4     6
 7  76.4  47.2     61.8  60.9  39.1     50       7
 8  94.6  32.9     63.8  61.9  14.7     38.3     8
 9  77.6  53       65.3  55.8  19.3     37.6     9
10  72.8  96.8     84.8  52.9  15.4     34.2    10
```